# can i use a variable for ardl testing

Tags: time-series

i have done unit root testing on my time series variable using both the adf and pp test. at level difference my variables all appeared non stationary.i used the option 'trend' and speratley 'drift' on stata when testing. however when testing them at first difference, the variable gross fixed capital formation was stationary when using 'drift' but not when including 'trend'. is this okay to still use for ardl cointergration testing?

Comment: what do you mean by ardl cointegration testing? You mean the Pesaran et al bounds test approach?

Comment: Yes sorry, forgot to include that.